# How to get the SHA of the checked out code with ansible git module?

Tags: git, ansible

I would like to store the currently checked out commit `SHA-1` hash for the version of code with Ansible.

I want to [`set_fact`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html) of this version for use in another role.

Comment: You mean the git commit ID of the repo the playbook is in?

Comment: Sorry I haven't explained it that well. Yes the git commit id or SHA-1 hash, but of a seperate git repo that the playbook checks out with the `git` module

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `git` module in Ansible returns this information for you, you just need to **register** it in a variable (variable is `gitresult` in the example below).

```
- hosts: web
  tasks:
    - name: Checkout repo
      git:
        repo=https://github.com/michalgasek/www-discogs.git
        dest=/vagrant/checkout
        update=yes
        accept_hostkey=yes
      register: gitresult

    - debug: msg="SHA-1 before git update is {{ gitresult.before }}"
    - debug: msg="SHA-1 after git update is {{ gitresult.after }}"
```

Running :

```
PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.2.201]

TASK [Checkout repo] ***********************************************************
ok: [192.168.2.201]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.2.201] => {
    "msg": "SHA-1 before git update is 87544e2ea1c8dec30e5fc68302caa262b10affda"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.2.201] => {
    "msg": "SHA-1 after git update is 87544e2ea1c8dec30e5fc68302caa262b10affda"
}
```

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Is there any way to use the git module to locally check the SHA-1, without relying on access to the remote repo? This is obviously possible (it is shown in a simple `git log` command), but the git module requires the `repo` param, and my testing seems to confirm that it breaks if it can't get access.

Comment: If the `git` module requires `repo` argument then it won't work. But you could use `command` module in the above use case: `command: git log --pretty=format:"%H" -n 1` or alternatively `command: git rev-parse HEAD` will give you SHA-1, just `register: gitresult` and your SHA-1 will be accessible in `{{ gitresult.std_out }}`

Comment: Yes, that is a good valid option. Through more detailed testing, I also discovered that setting `clone` and `update` both to false will prevent a download, and this was suggested in the official docs.